# how to filter result set based on one column distict values and discard rest using oracle

Tags: oracle

I have  a query that returns unique set of records consisting several columns . Even though entire row is unique , columns can can have duplicates . I want to keep only rows that consist of distinct values of certain columns and discard the rest of rows . What is the best method to do it

Sample dataset:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
10      Red     Book1   Large
10      Blue    Book1   Small
20      Blue    Book1   Small
30      Red     Book2   Medium
30      Blue    Book2   Small
```

desired result

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
10      Red     Book1   Large
30      Red     Book2   Medium
```

above example I keep the col3 distinct and discard rest randomly.

Comment: Please post some sample data, desired result and what you tried so far; you can have a look at [mcve] to build an example that can help people to help you

Comment: @Aleksej I have added a result set

Comment: In your result you extract one row for Book1, but how do you decide to keep the row with col4= Large and not, for example, a row with col4=Small? that is: how to decide which row to extract among a list of rows with the same value of col3? Do you need an ordering on the other columns?

Comment: I only need to extract one row for distinct value in col3. There is no need to consider any logic to decide what row to keep. anyone can be keep and discard the rest. just need one row for certain value in col 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for your example:

```
with test (col1, col2, col3, col4) as
(
  select 10, 'Red', 'Book1', 'Large'  from dual union all
  select 10, 'Blue','Book1', 'Small'  from dual union all
  select 20, 'Blue','Book1', 'Small'  from dual union all
  select 30, 'Red', 'Book2', 'Medium' from dual union all
  select 30, 'Blue','Book2', 'Small'  from dual
)
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from (
        select col1, col2, col3, col4,
               row_number() over ( partition by col3 order by col2 desc) countCol3
        from test
     )     
where countCol3 = 1
```

Here I decided to keep, in case of more than one row wit the same value of `col3`, the row with the minimum value of `col2`; this is only to fit your example, so you should edit the ordering part to better fit your need.